# How to extract zip file in node.js ( Compression method : Deflate64 )

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, extract

I need to extract zip files in node.js.
currently i am using decompress packages for extract, but its not working if compression method : Deflate64, its working only compression method : Deflate.
any other solution is there ?

I tried some packages like adm-zip,node-stream-zip,yauzl but not able to extract Deflate64 compression method files.

here is my code using yauzl.

```
const yauzl = require('yauzl');
exports.unzip = function (zipPath, targetDir, completeHandler, progressHandler, errHandler) {
this.createDirIfNotExist(targetDir);
yauzl.open(zipPath, { lazyEntries: true }, (err, zipfile) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    zipfile.readEntry();
    zipfile.on('entry', (entry) => {
        var fileDir = path.join(targetDir, entry.fileName);
      if (/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {
        // Directory entry, create directory
        // For example: fs.mkdirSync(entry.fileName);
        fs.mkdirSync(targetDir + entry.fileName, { recursive: true });
      } else {
        // File entry, extract file
        zipfile.openReadStream(entry, (err, readStream) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          // For example: readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(entry.fileName));
          const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileDir);
            readStream.pipe(writeStream);
          readStream.on('end', () => {
            zipfile.readEntry();
          });
        });
      }
    });
  
    zipfile.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Extraction completed.');
    });
  });
};
```

in this code getting error like : Uncaught Error: unsupported compression method: 9